# Git commit as part of previous commit

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

Is it possible to commit your changes as part of a previous commit? Like add to your most recent commit with whatever you just changed?

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history - commit with --amend

Comment: Just stage your new changes and do `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called amending.

```
git commit --amend
```

You can even change the commit message of the last commit.

```
git commit --amend --message "my new message"
```

It's worth knowing that even though the commit is the same one from a human perspective, the SHA hash will change, so if you were referring to it by hash for any purpose, the reference won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn the last two revisions into a single one:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
git commit --amend --no-edit # use the message from the (originally) 2nd to last revision
```

Or, you could set up a new message:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
git commit --amend -m "new message"
```